# Migration issue on getting ModuleName in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to migrate my App from Angular1.0.7 to 1.4.0. At one place I am trying to get moduleName by

```
$route.current.$$route.moduleName
```

which is not working now. I am stuck to go further since that is very important. How I can rewrite this part of code?

Comment: what does it actually return in your old version? What does this `moduleName` mean?

Comment: it usually returns the route name..if it is /admin/user it will return admin...i know i can use $location.path but still that needs some string ops..

Comment: well, for me `$location.path().split("/")[0]` looks much nicer than `$route.current.$$route.moduleName`. I think you should go for it

Comment: hmm..let me check if it works in all cases..

Comment: probably you need to take the 1st element instead of 0th as long as the path contains "/" in the beginning